# Apple store connect link

Tags: ios, store, connect

I ve published an Ios App with Apple store connect. 
Where can change the url associate at label "app support" and "development site" that is visibile in apple store in the description?
I see only url privacy link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change AppSupport URL when you submit a new version of the app.
[image]

Comment: thanks for answer but the app is already published. Prepare page not is present. I have only Ready for Sale and in this page the url change is locked.

Comment: i think you can't changes without submitting new build to appStore.

Comment: yes. I have submit now a  new binary version and the url is unlocked. Thanks